# PHP Array - foreach - print key value only if that key name exist in current array

Tags: php

I am getting a response from database in array like this:

```
Array ( [mage_form_post_status] => draft [mage_form_post_type] => post [mage_form_post_permission] => public [mage_form_post_author] => 1  [mage_form_post_redirect] => 0 )    
Array ( [mage_form_post_status] => draft [mage_form_post_type] => post [mage_form_post_permission] => public [mage_form_post_author] => 1  [mage_form_post_redirect] => 88 )
Array ( [mage_gym_name] => Fanna - test [mage_your_name] => John )
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display mage_gym_name  value only.
I have succeed to display it with this code:

```
foreach($gym_titles as $gym_title){

         print_r(unserialize($gym_title));
         echo '<br><br><br>';

}
```

Problem is that when there is no result, like in first two arrays I get 3 empty breaklines.

So I believe that I should wrap:

```
         print_r(unserialize($gym_title));
         echo '<br><br><br>';
```

In some kind of condition which should check if that current array contains that key name.

I have tried like this but it doesn't work:

```
 foreach($gym_titles as $gym_title){

        if (array_key_exists('mage_gym_name', $gym_title) {
                 echo "The 'first' element is in the array";

                 print_r(unserialize($gym_title));
                 echo '<br><br><br>';

        } else {
                 echo 'no such element in this array';
        }
}
```

Comment: Everything perfect, expect you forgot one little thing here: `if (array_key_exists('mage_gym_name', $gym_title)` a bracket and to unserialize the array.

Comment: I think you're missing a parenthesis on the `if(array_key_exists[...]` line

Comment: Thank You all for helping me with this. You were right, I have forget to unserialize. I have used code from AbraCadaver and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `unserialize()` before you check for the key:

```
foreach($gym_titles as $gym_title){

    $result = unserialize($gym_title);

    if(isset($result['mage_gym_name'])) {
        echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
        print_r($result);
        echo '<br><br><br>';
    } else {
        echo 'no such element in this array';
    }
}
```

I use `isset()`, feel free to use `array_key_exists()` if you must.

Comment: Thank You for helping me on this.